# How to get a shadow using SpriteMaterial and a DirectionalLight

Tags: javascript, three.js

My code :

#### Directional light :

```
light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
light.position.set(-50, 50, 300);
light.castShadow = true;
light.shadowDarkness = 0.4;
light.shadowMapWidth = 1024;
light.shadowMapHeight = 1024;
scene.add(light);
```

#### Sprite :

```
var spriteMaterial = new THREE.SpriteMaterial({map: texture});
var info = new THREE.Sprite( spriteMaterial );
info.castShadow = true;
info.scale.set(infoScale, infoScale, infoScale);
info.name = continent.label;
info.userData.continent = continent;
info.userData.id = continent.id;
info.userData.type = 'info';
hubInfos.push(info);
```

**Here is the result my aircraft has a shadow but not the sprite[image]**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sprites in three.js do not cast shadows.

One work-around is to use `PlaneGeometry` like so:

```
scene.add( plane );
plane.lookAt( camera );
```

Note: `LookAt()` will not work correctly if the plane is a child of a rotating object; it must be a child of the scene.

three.js r.74

Comment: Is it possible we can add a warning to threejs if you set castShadow for a Sprite object?

Comment: I think it would be preferable to add a notation in the docs.